# Log-likelihood using the link identity for poisson?

Tags: poisson-regression, likelihood, link-function

I understood the Log-likelihood using the link “log” for poisson, λ=exp(α+βx). But I can’t get the Log-likelihood in the case of “identity”, λ=α+βx. How do I get it?. The example is the following data. I’d like to get the l(θ) of identity about the data. Please give me some advice.

Log-likelihood using link=log for poisson, λ=exp(α+βx).

[image]

```
x=1,2,10
y=10,15,20
l(θ)=45α+240β−∑log(yi!)−exp(α+β)−exp(α+2β)−exp(α+10β)
```

Comment: I think this (https://www.stat.cmu.edu/~cshalizi/mreg/15/lectures/06/lecture-06.pdf) covers what you're talking about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the Poisson parameter $\lambda_i=\alpha+\beta x_i$, $i=1, \dotsc,n$, for $Y_i \sim \mathcal{Pois}(\lambda_i)$, independently. The Poisson pmf is $e^{-\lambda} \frac{\lambda^y}{y!}$, to get the likelihood just substitute in there for $\lambda$ the expression $\alpha+\beta x_i$, and multiply, giving
$$
L(\alpha,\beta) = \prod_{i=1}^n e^{-\alpha -\beta x_i} \frac{(\alpha+\beta x_i)^{y_i}}{y_i!}
$$
Taking the logarithm gives you the loglikelihood.

Comment: I got it! Thank you for your answer!

l(θ)=exp(-a-b)*(a+b)^10/10!)* (exp(-a-2*b)*(a+2*b)^15/15!)* (exp(-a-10*b)*(a+10*b)^20/20!